# JSF 2.0: <f:ajax>'s listener is not triggered

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, listener

In my code, I have a PrimeFaces' wizard component with several tabs as following:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:wizard flowListener="#{mrBean.flowControl}" widgetVar="wiz">
        <p:tab id="tab1"></p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab2"></p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab3">

            <h:selectOneMenu id="couponList" value="#{mrBean.coupon}"
                             converter="#{codeToCouponConverter}" >
                <f:ajax listener="#{mrBean.doSomething}" execute="@this"/>
                <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Choose one..." />
                <f:selectItems value="#{mrBean.coupons}" var="c" 
                               itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.name} - $ #{c.discount}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

This is the code for the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mrBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MrBean {
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
    private Coupon       coupon;

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    public String flowControl(FlowEvent event) {
        ...
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

In 1 of the tab, I have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` component which contains a `<f:ajax>` tag. I have no idea why the listener is only triggered when I choose the `Choose one...` option. When I choose any other options from the `mrBean.coupons` list, the listener is never triggered. In other words, I never saw any `DONE` printed on the console.

*UPDATE***: The problem turns out to be coming from the following `Converter`:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class CodeToCouponConverter implements Converter {
    @EJB
    private MrsBeanInterface mrsBean;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        String couponCode = value;
        if (value != null) return mrsBean.getCoupon(couponCode);
        else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Coupon c = (Coupon) value;
            return c.getId();

        } else return null;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public MrsBeanInterface getMrsBean() {
        return mrsBean;
    }

    public void setMrsBean(MrsBeanInterface mrsBean) {
        this.mrsBean = mrsBean;
    }
}
```

If I change the `<h:selectOneMenu>` as following:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="couponList" value="#{mrBean.couponCode}" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{mrBean.doSomething}" execute="@this"/>
    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Choose one..." />
    <f:selectItems value="#{mrBean.coupons}" var="c" 
                   itemValue="#{c.id}" itemLabel="#{c.name} - $ #{c.discount}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and update the `mrBean.doSomething` function as following:

```
@EJB
private MrsBeanInterface mrsBean;
private String couponCode;
private Coupon coupon;

public void doSomething() {
    this.coupon = mrsBean.getCoupon(couponCode);
    System.out.println("DONE");
}
```

everything works perfectly.

I would be very grateful if you could give me an explanation of what I have done wrong with the `Converter`.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: Have you tried adding event='change' attribute in <f:ajax> tab?

Comment: @djaqeel If I'm now wrong, it's the default value. I have just tried and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Just curious , try to simlify the label , display only the .name without the dollar and the other...

Comment: @Daniel it does not work as well :(

Comment: I would have get rid from that choose one than strip from wizard and so on.. to find out what cause the weird behavior...

Comment: Converter looks okay at quick glance (getter/setter is unnecessary for EJB btw). Since you've explicitly shown the piece in a `<p:wizard>`, are you implying that it works the expected way outside the `<p:wizard>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use #{mrBean.doSomething()} with the braces or add the event parameter to the method.